# default selected option for html select using javascript in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, default

Hello I have a select element and I am trying to set a default option for that select element. But my code isn't working in IE. Is there any way around for this??

```
if(objOption.value == selectedoption)
{ alert(objOption.value);
objOption.defaultSelected = true;
}
```

I am able to retreive the option, and its value, but am unable to set the defaultSelected value.

Comment: Got the answer!! <pre><code> objOption.selected=true; </code> <br> works in IE. :D

Answer (score 4):

As stated in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533716%28VS.85%29.aspx), the `defaultSelected` property is only used if you click an `<input type="reset" />`.

To immediately select the `<option>`, you should also set the `selected` property to `true`.